# How can I exclude a file from a git repository forever?

Tags: git, github

I have a github project that's set up with a ll the build files and everything just the way I want them (by someone else more able than myself), and I want to start a new project with all those settings. However, this project doesn't belong in the repo.

How can I systematically exclude everything in this project from the repo?

Comment: Use a .gitignore: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Comment: I didn't understand very well. Do you want to copy only the setting files of an existing project?

Comment: .gitignore doesn't un-track files

Comment: If all the files you want to keep are in a given folder you might try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository

Answer (score 0):

Start a new repository for the new project and copy the files you want the new project to use into it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, there is a github project (that is not yours) that has some files that you'd like to include in your new projects; however, you just want the files, not the git repo history.

If that is correct, here is how you do that:

```
% mkdir my-new-project
% cd !$
% curl -#L https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz --strip 1
```

That will put the project's files into your current directory and won't bring the project's git repo along with it.